Siri not recognizing the parameter in the phrase
I'm developing an iOS app using the App Intents framework. I've created an 'OpenShowIntent' that should allow users to open a show from outside the app by either:
Invoking a shortcut and providing a show name, or
Asking Siri: 'Open [show name] in [app name]'
The shortcut works correctly when invoked manually through the Shortcuts app. However, when I try to use the Siri voice command, Siri recognizes the app name but doesn't seem to capture the show name. Siri loads but then doesn't complete the action and return "Something went wrong". What might be the problem here?
OpenShowIntent.swift:
import Foundation
import AppIntents
import Models

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct OpenShowIntent: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Open a Show"
    static var openAppWhenRun = true

    @Parameter(title: "Show", optionsProvider: ShowEntityQuery())
    var show: ShowEntity?

    @Parameter(title: "Show Name")
    var showName: String

    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        Summary("Open \(\.$showName) in (APP NAME)")
    }

    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & ProvidesDialog {
        
        var showToOpen: ShowEntity

        if let show = show {
            showToOpen = show
        } else {
            let params = ElasticSearchParams(query: showName)
            let searchResults = try await IntentsHelper.getShows(searchParams: params)
            let entities = searchResults.map { show in
                ShowEntity(id: show.id, name: show.displayName, posterUrl: show.posterImageUrl)
            }
            showToOpen = try await $show.requestDisambiguation(
                among: entities,
                dialog: "Choose a show from this list?"
            )
        }
        let deepLink = DeepLink(
            type: .show(
                showId: showToOpen.id,
                showDateStr: nil,
                voucher: nil,
                reviewModalParams: nil
            )
        )
        let url = try deepLink.createURL(source: nil)
        IntentsHelper.openLink(url: url)
        return .result(dialog: "Show '\(showToOpen.name)' opened successfully.")
    }
}

ShowEntity.swift:
import Foundation
import AppIntents
import Models

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct ShowEntity: AppEntity {
    typealias DefaultQuery = ShowEntityQuery
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var posterUrl: URL?

    static var typeDisplayRepresentation: TypeDisplayRepresentation = "Show"

    var displayRepresentation: DisplayRepresentation {
        var image: DisplayRepresentation.Image?
        if let imageUrl = posterUrl {
            image = DisplayRepresentation.Image(url: imageUrl)
        }
        return DisplayRepresentation(
            title: LocalizedStringResource(stringLiteral: name),
            subtitle: nil,
            image: image
        )

    }
    static var defaultQuery = ShowEntityQuery()
    init(id: Int, name: String, posterUrl: URL?) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.posterUrl = posterUrl
    }
}

ShowEntityQuery.swift:
import Foundation
import AppIntents
import Models

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct ShowEntityQuery: EntityStringQuery {
    func entities(for identifiers: [Int]) async throws -> [ShowEntity] {
        let params = ElasticSearchParams(showIds: identifiers)
        let searchResult = try await IntentsHelper.getShows(searchParams: params)
        return searchResult.map { show in
            ShowEntity(id: show.id, name: show.displayName, posterUrl: show.posterImageUrl)
        }
    }

    func suggestedEntities() async throws -> [ShowEntity] {
        let params = ElasticSearchParams(
            showIds: BookmarksManager.sharedManager.getBookmarkShowIdsAsArray()
        )
        let searchResult = try await IntentsHelper.getShows(searchParams: params)
        return searchResult.map { show in
            ShowEntity(id: show.id, name: show.displayName, posterUrl: show.posterImageUrl)
        }
    }

    func entities(matching query: String) async throws -> [ShowEntity] {
        let params = ElasticSearchParams(query: query)
        print("entities(matching:) called with query: \(query)")
        let searchResult = try await IntentsHelper.getShows(searchParams: params)
        return searchResult.map { show in
            ShowEntity(id: show.id, name: show.displayName, posterUrl: show.posterImageUrl)
        }
    }
}

ShortcutsProvider.swift:
import Foundation
import AppIntents

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct TTShortcuts: AppShortcutsProvider {
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
        return [
            AppShortcut(
                intent: OpenShowIntent(),
                phrases: [
                    "View show in \(.applicationName)",
                    "Open \(\.$showName) in \(.applicationName)",
                    "Show \(\.$showName) in \(.applicationName)",
                    "Find \(\.$showName) in \(.applicationName)",
                    "Search for \(\.$showName) in \(.applicationName)"
                ],
                shortTitle: "Open show",
                systemImageName: "pencil.circle"
            )
        ]
    }
    static var shortcutTileColor: ShortcutTileColor = .blue
}

I want the user to activate siri and tell "Open {showname} in {appName}" and Siri will open the show in the app.

There seems to be an issue where Siri might not run functions correctly with certain languages, like Chinese. However, if you switch Siri to English, these functions might work as expected. This suggests that the problem could be due to how Siri handles different languages.
Here’s what I did to troubleshoot and fix the issue:
Steps to Fix the Siri Issue

Set a Breakpoint to See if the Function is Called:

Open your project in Xcode and find the code for OpenShowIntent and ShowEntityQuery.
Set a breakpoint in the function where the showName query is handled (e.g., entities(matching:) in ShowEntityQuery).
Run your app and try the Siri command: "Open [show name] in [app name]."
Check if the function is actually being called when Siri processes the command.


Check if the Function is Called:

If the function is not called: Siri may not be processing the input correctly or there might be a language issue.
If the function is called: The problem could be somewhere else in your intent logic, but at least Siri is recognizing the command correctly.


Change Siri’s Language to English:

If the function isn't getting called, try changing Siri’s language to English:

Go to Settings > Siri & Search > Language on your device.
Choose English as the preferred language.


Then, test the Siri command again.



In my case, switching Siri to English solved the problem.
